# How to use passifox with keepassX ?

Tags: keepassx

I found a [fork](https://github.com/keithbennett/keepassx/releases) of keepassX with a built-in support for HTTP but I have absolutely no idea how to make it work with passifox. I didn't found any doc neither.

I already have keefox + keepass with mono but this is unconvenient.

What should be done to link passifox and keepassX ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nothing was needed.

It appears that Keefox was causing troubles. Once disabled, passifox can communicate with keepassX and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Well passifox and keepasshttp both require Keepass v2. Unless you are using the alpha version of KeepassX, it will not be possible because v1 uses Keepass v1 databases.

I would suggest contacting the KeepassX authors and discussing with them.

UPDATE: OK, I can see that the fork does use the alpha v2 version. Again though I suggest contacting the author.